# YouTube player in modal window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, modal-dialog

I'm looking to have my page display a div as a modal and then play a YouTube video.  I'm able to get the video to play as expected (code below) but when I switch to a hidden div upon a filtering action, the div that was hidden upon page load doesn't pass the data-src value to the modal.  I've tried detaching the modal via jQuery and doing an insertAfter() but the Bootstrap modal keeps the same data-src value.

Two questions: 1) does YouTube have a way to embed into a modal window natively?  2) What am I missing regarding the DOM and how it's holding onto the initial data-src value I'm passing to the modal?

HTML for links (click):

```
<div class="video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sa_5fh_OFcc" data-target="#myModal">Overview</div>
<div class="video-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/TBCyYTNBObI" data-target="#myModal">Installation Instructions</div>
```

HTML for modal window:

```
<!-- Modal for video-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>        
<!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="" id="video"   frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

jQuery to get data-src value (YouTube link) and create video object

```
$('.video-btn').click(function()
{
$videoSrc = $(".video-btn").data( "src" );
});
```

JavaScript/jQuery to open modal and play video:

```
    // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e)
    {
        // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. 
        console.log($("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc));

        //$("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp'enablejsapi=1" ); 
    });//#myModal show

    // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e)
    {
        // a poor man's stop video
        $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc); 
        //remove modal from DOM
        //$("#myModal").detach();
    });//#myModal close
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this plugin https://sorgalla.com/lity/. Very simple to use

```
<a href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSGBVzeBUbk" data-lity>iFrame Youtube</a>
```

and then just add this script.

```
var lightbox = lity('//www.youtube.com/watch?v=XSGBVzeBUbk');
$(document).on('click', '[data-lightbox]', lity);
```

Comment: Easy to use.  Works well.

Comment: glad that helps